# Efficient use of LocationManager in Android

Tags: android, gps, broadcastreceiver, locationmanager

I am trying to optimise an Android application which must achieve the following:

- Every hour, retrieve the GPS location and doSomeWork()
- At any other time if the device moves more than @MINIMUM_DISTANCE, increase update frequency to something like 5 minutes to log the movement, when movement ends we can return to the hourly updates.

Now, AlarmManager firing every hour works a treat for the first requirement. It's a fine battery efficient method of accomplishing this task. However I'm unsure how to best accomplish the second requirement.

Should I:

- Register an AlarmManager which fires every 5 minutes in tandem with the hourly timer? Register LocationManager each time and attempt to pull off a location, compare to previous location to determine whether movement has occurred.
- Register a LocationManager after my hourly wakeup with a minimum distance parameter equal to my required minimum movement.
- Something else?

I can see pros and cons to each approach.

Using the LocationManager minimum distance parameter seems to me to be the more concise solution but I'm concerned about battery drain, will this keep the GPS running hot the whole time regardless of whether my application is receiving updates? I am also not sure where the best place to register the receiver would be, I understand it's poor practice (not to mention nigh impossible) to keep a service running 100% of the time.

Yes I am new to Android! About to go and test the behaviour of LocationManager.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution, which is working well, is to keep NETWORK_PROVIDER (and PASSIVE on the off chance  I can get some updates for free) registered and listening any time the GPS_PROVIDER is not. If movement is seen outside the previously retrieved location, I can switch to full GPS to monitor the movement.

Accuracy is poor, but at least sufficiently good. Battery consumption is remarkably low.

Comment: I think this is actually a great answer. I've been struggling with how to get an alert based on distance travelled.

Comment: Do be aware that the network listener can give you some very unreliable results, for instance I've had alerts that I'm 15km from my previous location with a given accuracy of 1.5km when in fact I have not moved at all. In my application I always double check with the true gps provider to ascertain whether the fix was somewhat correct.

Comment: I had a similar experience in my living room yesterday with the NetworkProvider "taking me on a trip along the road". I too hadn't moved.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if user gets in car and drives? If you have `LocationManager` set up for minimum distance, you'll get a callback relatively quickly (well, I don't know what your minimum distance is, but...). In the other case, you might have to wait 5 whole minutes until you recognize that the user has moved.

However, if you really only need once-every-5-minutes updates, then I would definitely use the `AlarmManager` method, as that will guarantee that you won't be doing anything with GPS in between the 5 minute slots.

Be aware though, that it can take some time for the GPS to get a fix if the user has moved and the GPS wasn't on. So don't expect that you will be able to get an accurate fix immediately on firing up GPS.

Comment: That's precisely the problem with the AlarmManager method, and the reason I'd prefer to be able to have a LocationManager registered all the time, however I am not sure whether such an approach is feasible from a battery life PoV. This application must be active as close to 100% of the time the device is turned on as possible, therefore battery impact is something I'm very concerned about.

Comment: I'd _like_ to keep the LocationManager registered to detect the movement, then remove it and fall back to five-minute alarms for the actual tracking. I really only need it for that "started moving" notification, I can handle the rest.

Comment: I would suggest that you actually test it. Implement both, add logging to determine battery drain and use it in ral world conditions. Then compare. You will then be able to decide based on empirical data. The real problem here is that the individual phone manufacturers all implement their own low-level GPS stuff, so it is difficult to know exactly how this is implemented without testing it yourself.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for your comments. I have been running my own battery tests, as I suspected keeping a GPS listener registered even with sensible minimum distance and time parameters drains the battery to dead within 12 hours on the model I'm working with (Samsung Galaxy Ace). I've had some success using the NETWORK listener for my movement notification as battery usage with this is greatly reduced. I noticed in the docs for the latest OS update it is now mandatory for manufacturers to implement min time and distance correctly - a welcome change.

Comment: -1: the problem with LocationManager is that it doesn't offer a method of checking JUST for distance. It will check for distance AND time. So it will not alert you when you have moved far enough UNTIL THE TIME IS UP.